# Improve query in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to improve this query inside a stored procedure, the performance with lots of data broke the application. Is there any way to make it faster?

I need to collect certain columns from several tables to build a dashboard in my app web, others columns I collected in other query and joined in my controller through classes.

EDIT: this query is a part from dynamically transaction, they can change the database.

```
SELECT 
    a.fact_num as cotizacion, a.comentario, m.co_cli, k.cli_des, 
    m.co_ven, l.ven_des, m.fec_emis, m.fec_venc, m.campo8, 
    a.reng_num, a.co_art, g.art_des, a.co_alma, b.fact_num as pedido, 
    c.fact_num as factura, d.fact_num as despacho, e.cob_num as cobro, 
    f.fec_venc as fecha_venc, f.fec_emis as fecha_pedido,
    h.odp_num as ord_produccion, h.co_ced as cedula, i.req_num as requisicion, 
    j.ent_num as cierre 
FROM 
    reng_cac a
LEFT JOIN  
    cotiz_c m ON a.fact_num = m.fact_num
LEFT JOIN 
    reng_ped b ON a.co_art = b.co_art AND a.fact_num = b.num_doc AND b.tipo_doc = 'T'
LEFT JOIN 
    pedidos f ON b.fact_num = f.fact_num 
LEFT JOIN 
    reng_fac c ON b.fact_num = c.num_doc AND a.co_art = c.co_art AND c.tipo_doc = 'P'
LEFT JOIN 
    reng_ndd d ON c.fact_num = d.num_doc AND a.co_art = d.co_art AND d.tipo_doc = 'F'
LEFT JOIN 
    reng_cob e ON c.fact_num = e.doc_num AND e.tp_doc_cob = 'FACT'
LEFT JOIN 
    art g ON a.co_art = g.co_art
LEFT JOIN 
    spodp h ON b.fact_num = h.doc_ori AND b.co_art = h.co_art 
LEFT JOIN 
    spreqalm i ON h.odp_num = i.odp_num
LEFT JOIN 
    spcierre j ON h.odp_num = j.odp_num 
LEFT JOIN 
    clientes k ON m.co_cli = k.co_cli
LEFT JOIN 
    vendedor l ON m.co_ven = l.co_ven
WHERE 
    a.fact_num BETWEEN '0' AND '999999999' 
    AND m.fec_emis BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '30/06/2012'
    AND m.co_cli BETWEEN '' AND 'þþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþ' 
ORDER BY 
    a.fact_num, a.reng_num ASC
```

Comment: If you want to improve performance the first step is to collect the actual/ estiamted plan: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189562.aspx

Comment: have you wondered to use aggregate functions such as sum, max ... with group by clause ? if it fits in your case.

Comment: are you sure all your joins are really `LEFT` and `fact_num` is a string?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have the actual / estimated plan but is too large, how copy that in the post?

Comment: @Boody let me see is the agregate functions work perfectly in that query

Comment: @IvanStarostin well, I saw the joins and yes, all the joins is `LEFT` but if you can see other type of joins, please tell me about it, `fact_num` is `INT`

Comment: You do a left join on table `vendedor` but then you use a `WHERE` on it which makes it a inner join. You probably need to move your `AND m. pieces into the left join or do an inner join. Are you doing all those left joins for a reason?

Comment: Now that you have your execution plan, take a look and find the largest percentage in there and see if it is a table scna or index scan. Also the query plan will recommend indexes if it can.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the `WHERE` works to all query or the last `LEFT` join? I think in my little knowledge is work to the all query, isn't? Sorry for my english is a very poor in this time... The reason for the all `LEFT` joins is bring back all the necesary fields all those tables to build a dashboard

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Ok, I will do that.

Comment: LEFT JOIN as you have it here means bring back all the records from `reng_cac` and only those that match on `fact_num` from `cotiz_c`. If a record _doesn't_ match in `cotiz_c` then all fields in `cotiz_c` will be NULL. So first important question is: can there be a `fact_num` value in `reng_cac` that **doesn't** exist in `cotiz_c`? If the answer is _no_ then you should be using inner joins not left joins.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, `reng_cac` have all the rengs from `cotiz_c` is a child table

Comment: @DerSchwarzeKönig, a had no question about what's written in your post, I asked about your real data model. As @NickMcDermaid mentioned you already have logically `inner` joins because of filters applied in `where`. And many other joins don't look like really `LEFT`. Joins described: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472.aspx And since you understand and approve that `fact_num` is `int` - why are you attempting to apply string filter to it? what are those quotes there for?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I need all the data to the left table with the matched in the right table, those quotes in the INT field is a mistake from my part, I run the query again with the execution plan and the major consumption is in that part of the query `reng_ped b ON a.co_art = b.co_art AND a.fact_num = b.num_doc AND b.tipo_doc = 'T'` and the others similars in quotes @NickMcDermaid

Comment: So regarding the link I gave - which join is that? `LEFT` or `INNER`? And do you have any indexes on columns you are joining and filtering by (since you are not showing execution plan)?

Comment: @IvanStarostin `LEFT` to me but if you think is wrong, I can change that, The only indexes are in PK values aka `a.fact_num` and `b.co_art` here the execution plan [link](http://imgur.com/kOVrN2A)

Comment: Build indexes for "columns you are joining and filtering by". And link is to the picture with a lonely key lookup. It has nothing common with the query in your question.

Comment: @DerSchwarzeKönig http://stackoverflow.com/a/20298671/5921826

Comment: @IvanStarostin the execution plan is very large to copy to an image... How to insert that here? Thanks you...

Comment: Build indexes for "columns you are joining and filtering by".

Comment: @IvanStarostin How doing that? If not direct to the DB...

Answer (score 0):

As Nick commented, you always need to run your query in a execution plan. There are some points you need to consider. For instance, having a lot of `LEFT JOIN`s will reduce the performance. Try to see if you can use `INNER JOIN`s where possible. Check if you have proper indexes. If you can attach your execution plan to your question, you will get more helpful answers.